# Treemap Echarts Dynamic label text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, echarts

Can you make the text size dynamically dependant on the size of a box on a treemap label?

all I can find in the docs is how to hardcode it

https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-treemap.label.fontFamily

```
 label: {
      fontSize: 16
    }
```

The idea being that the smaller the box the smaller the font.

[image: map]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this.
Probably the best way would be to add a `labelLayout` function to the series. There is an example in the eCharts GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/apache/echarts/blob/master/test/treemap-obama.html). So the series in the provided example would end up looking like this:

```
      series: [
        {
          name: 'Disk Usage',
          type: 'treemap',
          visibleMin: 300,
          label: {
            show: true,
            formatter: '{b}'
          },
          labelLayout: function (params) {
            if (params.rect.width < 5 || params.rect.height < 5) {
                return {  fontSize: 0  };
            }
            return {
                fontSize: Math.min(Math.sqrt(params.rect.width * params.rect.height) / 10, 20)
            };
          },
          itemStyle: {
            borderColor: '#fff'
          },
          levels: getLevelOption(),
          data: diskData
        }
      ]
```

alternatively, you could alter the `label` and add a `formatter` to be a function and which pipes through `rich` formatting. In the example, send in the Parameters object and we grab the root element value (total overall Disk Usage from the provided example), then find a ratio of the current value to the total value.

```
          label: {
            show: true,
            formatter: function (params) {
                let totSize=  params.treePathInfo[0].value;
                let size=(params.value/totSize)*100;
                if (size>8) {
                   return `{l|${params.name}}`
                }
                if (size>2) {
                   return `{m|${params.name}}`
                }
                return `{s|${params.name}}`
            },
            rich: {
              l: {
                fontSize: 20,
              },
              m: {
                fontSize: 15,
              },
              s: {
                fontSize: 10,
              }
            },
          },
```